# CodeRush XPress | Code Intelliassist Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, coderush-xpress

I've installed coderush and wanted to refactor my code. I also tried to do some things they did in the introduction video. But the only way I get into the coderush intelliassist is the right-click context menu in the editor.

Can you help me to change the shortcut? By default the short cut should be <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>

I'm using Windows 7 Pro - German + Visual Studio 08 Pro - German if this is important.

Comment: Seems like you should accept ZombieSheep's answer below.. You indicated in you comment that it was the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the default is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) but you can change it as follows...

Go to `DevExpress -> Options` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) Then select IDE, and then shortcuts in the left hand pane.

Click the search biutton at the top of the option window, select the "Command" tab, and look for "Refactor"

Answer (score 6):

With Coderush XPress, the Refactor shortcut is NOT BOUND to a key by default! 
You Have to add a shortcut for it manually (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, IDE, Shortcuts, Add New)

Also a good setting is in Editor->Smart Tags -> Use DXCore smart tags, so that you know, when VS has a refactoring or help (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> ) e.g. Imports, or when Coderush has.

Comment: Bug or feature?  Seems a bit odd as the video tutorial makes a very big deal of this shortcut.

Comment: *Ctrl* + *`* has been the default shortcut for as long as I've used CodeRush Xpress (roughly a couple of years).